# Bootstrap Offset is Applied at Wrong Time?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tlbaxter99/t7hu3b8a/1/).

Notice the blue panel has class `col-md-offset-2`. My understanding is that this class should only be applied when the viewport is in "medium mode". But if you stretch the viewport to large, you'll see the blue panel is offset by 2.

Again, I thought `col-md-offset-2` only applies to "medium mode". Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

No, the bootstrap media queries that these sizes are based on have the following break points;

- `col-xs-` Extra small devices Phones (<768px)
- `col-sm-` Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
- `col-md-` Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
- `col-lg-` Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

There is no upper limit to `col-sm-`, `col-md-`, or `col-lg-` elements, and conversly no lower limit to `col-xs-` elements. So simply using `col-sm-` will cover all windows with a width of 768px or greater, and `col-xs-` will cover all windows and devices with a smaller width.

If you want to have different behaviour on large screens, you can use a `col-lg-` class along with `col-md-` and/or any of the other classes.